# Additive character sum over intersection of additive and multiplicative subgroups of finite fields

Tags: finite-fields, analytic-number-theory, characters, exponential-sum

Let $H$ be a multiplicative subgroup of the finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$ with $q$ elements, say $H$ is the subgroup of $d$-th powers, $d \mid q-1$. Let $L$ be a subspace of $\mathbb{F}_q$ over some base, say $\mathbb{F}_p$ where $p = \text{char}(\mathbb{F}_q)$. Let $\psi$ be a non-trivial additive character of $\mathbb{F}_q$. Assuming that $H, L, H \cap L$, are not trivial, do we know some good bounds for
$$
|S| = \left|\sum_{x \in H \cap L} \psi(x)\right|?
$$
Thanks.

Comment: You can write the indicator function of $H$ using multiplicative characters and the indicator function of $L$ using additive characters.. This rewrites your sum in terms of Gauss' sums all right. But I don't know if it gives anything good :-(

Comment: Thanks. I gave it a try using a bit Fourier and what you mentioned. I get a result under the assumption that $\psi = \psi_b$ with $b \in \mathbb{F}_p^*$. What I get: if $L \leq \ker(\text{Tr})$, then $|S| \leq |H||L|/(q-1) + q^{1/2}$. If $L \not\leq \ker(T_{q^n|p})$, then $|S| \leq q^{1/2}$. That is, the bound on $|S|$ is never worse than the size of Gauss sums.